# Cell reuse, hide show the buttons inside cell based on some conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a created a tableview cell in the nib file and added a button to it, and created an outlet to the button named as actionButton. Now, based on some condition, I want the button to be hidden or unhidden. I used the code below, so when the model, object.hasButton property is YES, I unhide the button and show otherwise. This code looks simple to me and I dont think that there should be a reuse issue, since it has either/else condition, so it should hide for the false boolean and unhide for the true boolean conditions. But, all the cell, no matter what their value is shows the button. Could somebody please help me, I have been trying to debug this but I dont seem to figure out the problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  MyObject * object = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.delegate = self;
  if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    cell.delegate = self;

  }


  cell.tableItem = object;
  UIButton *button = cell.actionButton;

  if(object.hasButton){
    [button setHidden:NO];
  }else{
    [button setHidden:YES];

  }

  return cell;

}
```

It seems like the problem was with threading. I was doing some operation inside the managedObjectContext performBlock:andWait method like this,

```
 [newChildContext performBlockAndWait:^{
  count = [newChildContext countForFetchRequest:req error:NULL];
      if(count > 0)
        hasButton = YES;
      else
        hasButton = NO;
  }];
```

And then updating the model like this,

```
    myObject.hasButton = hasButton;
```

May be this was the problem, so I wrapped it inside the @synchronized(myObject) block to update the hasButton bool and it seems to be fine now.

```
  @synchronzied(myObject){
      myButton.hasButton = hasButton;
    }
```

Could it be this thing ?

Comment: issue may occur if table is not reloading.please update full code to debug

Comment: Have you checked the outlet connections in interface builder and the values in `object`?

Comment: I have edited it, please check the above correction. I am not sure if that was the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

calling if (object.hasButton) simply checks if the property hasButton exists. it probably does exist, so it returns YES!

What you want is to check the value stored in that property, like this:

```
if (object.hasButton == YES)
```

Comment: I guess you are talking about the objective c objects, but my hasButton is a primitive type and so I think it wouldn't work the way you stated. The condition if (object.hasButton) will evaluate to true, if and only if the hasObject property is true or BOOL YES.

Comment: when you set a breakpoint and observe the state, do the facts confirm your assumptions? ie, does the else block ever run?

Comment: Sorry, I took sometime to debug. I fixed it, I guess it was related to concurrency. I tried the debugging as you said and it shows the true bool value for those object for which I have not set any value. Clearly, it seems like the issue with synchronization  and so the synchrozed block solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyObject` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` then it's `hasButton` property type is `NSNumber *` instead of `BOOL`. Since that `NSNumber` is an existing object - non nil - regardless if it's value is `YES` or `NO` `myObject.hasButton` evaluates to `TRUE` in boolean expression. Use `[myObject.hasButton booleanValue]` instead. also on setting that value use `anObject.hasButton = @(hasButton)`.

Comment: myObject is not a NSManagedObject subclass, see above the managedObjectContext is simply used to count the number of objects here. myObject is a subclass of NSObject and so the hasButton is a BOOL property. Based on the count, it simply sets the value of hasButton for myObject.